# What am I doing wrong with this simple javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/LvdcU/3/

I don't understand why I keep getting the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: updatetotalorderCals is not defined

I'm sure this has everything to do with my limited js knowledge.

**UPDATE:**

So the original example error has been resolved, but when applying it to my real-world code, the error returns. I've update jsFiddle with all of the applicable code: http://jsfiddle.net/LvdcU/8/, (probably more than necessary this time) in hopes of getting this working. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/LvdcU/4/

Comment: Use "no wrap (head)" instead of "onDomReady"

Comment: So does that mean when I implement the real version I have to move it to the head and not wrap it in a document ready function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a scope issue.  You have the fiddle set to `onDomReady`.  If you view the source of the page created by the fiddle, you will see this:

```
var VanillaRunOnDomReady = function() {
    function updatetotalorderCals() {
        alert("It worked!");

    }
}
```

Because your function is being placed within another function, it is not accessible outside of that function.  Change it to `no wrap (head)` and you will see that it works.

Comment: NullUserException made this example of basically the same answer: http://jsfiddle.net/LvdcU/4... I am trying to understand how to apply this answer to my real world application. Could you help me understand how to apply this so I keep the proper scope?

Comment: Just don't wrap it in anything and it will be global and work.

Comment: I don't know if you are still interested, (you've been very generous already), but when I apply this to my real world code, the error is back. I thought I had done a good job when I scaled it down. I added it here: http://jsfiddle.net/LvdcU/7/

Comment: Your new issue is this line:  `var totalorderCals += thesecalsTotal;`  += means that you want to add to that variable, but `var` means that you are creating a new variable.  You can't add to a variable that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Thanks for that advice, I can see how that would be wrong, (that's my lack of experience showing)... but does that resolve the issue for you? I am still seeing the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: updatetotalorderCals is not defined

Comment: You also need to remove the `<script>` tags from javascript section of the fiddle.